# Declare an array of strings in class header / Assignement in constructor - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm creating a little game in C++. I want to make the declaration of my map in the class and make the assignation in the constructor of the class.

I'm on it since 2 days and it blow my mind (I put it in global for go ahead for the moment).

Here is my files :

**map.cpp**

```
Map::Map() : width(21), height(21)
{
  this->array[] = {"011111111111111111110",
                   "012222222212222222210",
                   // Some strings //
                   "011111111111111111110"};
}
```

**map.hpp**

```
class                   Map
{
  const unsigned short  width;
  const unsigned short  height;
 public:
  extern std::string array[21];
  Map();
  ~Map();
};
```

Can someone help me with this / explain how to do that ? I tried many solutions on this forum but I didnt succeed :/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of array: it will be much more easier to work with it.